# Python - segmentation error in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, sigpipe

My program is coded in Python, and it calls a bash script in a vte window:

[image]

In 14.04 or 14.10 ubuntu system, no problem. (python 2.7.8)

But, in ubuntu 12.04, the window closes with this message: (python 2.7.3)

```
segmentation error
```

To debug, I've tried to use `gdb` with this line:

```
gdb -ex r --args python my_program.py
```

The output of gdb at the end is:

```
Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
0xb7fdd416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

I know it's a problem with the bash script, but I don't know realy what is the problem. The line to call the bash script is:

```
self.child_pid = self.v.fork_command(None, ['/bin/bash', cli, '-f', '-d', dest, '-u', adresse, v])
```

It is possible to debug this for ubuntu 12.04 ? How can I do ?

Comment: What are the arguments to `fork_command`? Isn't the first argument the command and the second a list of the arguments?

Comment: Thanks for your response - The error is the same when I use `self.child_pid = self.v.fork_command(cli, ['/bin/bash', '-f', '-d', dest, '-u', adresse, v])`

Comment: I don't know the library, just trying to help out. Do you have any calls to fork_command that **do** work? can you show them?

Comment: The bug is aleatory: it can appear either at the beginning, either at the end of the bash script. The script is using ffmpeg, but I will try to use another script to see the result.

Comment: Ok, so I tried another script: just `echo 'foo'` and there's no bug.

Comment: What is in `cli`? what are you trying to run?

Comment: It's a script to download a TV channel videos podcasts. It uses avconv or ffmpeg. There are 240 lines in this script, if you want to see the complete code I can send you a link (but you can't try it, there's country limitations if you're not in France)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66983/discussion-between-reut-sharabani-and-guillaume).

Comment: Hi Reut, I think I have solved the problem with adding in the bash script `sleep 1` after the command ffmpeg. Now, I can dl a list of videos without problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with insering a `sleep 1` in the bash script (cli), just after the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${M3U2}" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${Directory}/${PROG}_${ID}.mkv"
sleep 1
```